# How to Troubleshoot media queries on different browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, web, responsive-design

I have a website (http://www.sealinesd.com) that works just fine most of the time...but sometimes the browser (Firefox and Chrome) will determine the wrong screen size and show the site wrong. The same computer will show it differently on two different browsers: one browser will determine that the screen is 960-1240 and the other will correctly see that it's over 1240. I can't figure this out.  Anybody have some good tools for troubleshooting this issue, or better yet, know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  Some of my browsers had a tiny bit of zoom magnification.  That was screwing up how the browser pixel size was read because browser zoom basically stretches the pixels: 200% zoom on a 1024x768 screen will be read as a 612x384 screen.  I changed the media queries in CSS to use ems instead of pixels and that fixed the issue.  If you have this issue, just go into your style sheet and change the pixels to ems by dividing pixels by 16 and adding "em" to the end instead of "px".

Example: "@media only screen and (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1240px) {"

WOULD BECOME   "@media only screen and (min-width: 60em) and (max-width: 77em) {"

Now users can zoom without changing the query because em (the length of the letter "m") is a measurement that is based on the text size, which is changing proportionally to the page.